# Change build configuration artifacts manually

Tags: teamcity

I am using TC10.x and one of my build generates an artifact which is then loaded in one of my custom configuration tabs.

Now after 10 runs, I wanted to change something in that file, so i edited all the artifacts that are created in .buildserver/../../artifacts folder.

When i go to the build configuration and downloaded the artifacts and see the contents are all changed but when i click on the link in the teamcity, it still loads the old stuff how can i work around this?

Do i need to bounce the teamcity server instance or the agent?

Comment: Is there a proxy server between you and TeamCity server? It could be cached response.

Comment: I am using Apache to redirect the link that comes in to teamcity. I will read on how to clear the apaxhe cache and see . Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the apache web server resolved the issue. New files were taken up.
Could not see cache folder mention in the conf file, nor found any cache folder under apache or c:\program data etc.